# Sidekiq job not being queued

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rails-activejob

There is a chain of state machine callbacks that invoke `ActiveJob::Base` classes to process sequential phases of an order lifecycle.

I am running into a problem where the second job in the sequence is not being enqueued and no errors are being printed to the terminal.

The second job is

```
class WriteEncodedPreviewImageToFilesJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :imagery_queue

  def perform(order)
    run_phase_of_order_lifecycle(order)
  end

  private
  def run_phase_of_order_lifecycle(order)
    begin
      BackgroundWorkers::EncodedPreviewImageWriter.work(order)
    ensure
      order.render_final_image
    end
  end
end
```

And it is being invoked here:

```
class PreAuthorizeStripePaymentJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :stripe_queue

  def perform(order)
    run_phase_of_order_lifecycle(order)
  end

  private
  def run_phase_of_order_lifecycle(order)
    response = create_stripe_charge(order)
    if response['failure_code'] == nil
      order.stripe_charge_id = response['id']
      order.save!
      order.write_encoded_preview_image_to_files   # this line here!!!
    end
    response
  end

  def create_stripe_charge(order)
    Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => (order.original[:order][:price] * 100).round,
      :currency => 'gbp',
      :capture => false,
      :source => order.stripe_id,
      :description => "Charge for Order with id: #{order.id}",
      :receipt_email => order.original[:order][:user_email]
    )
  end
end
```

Because of the callback defined in this module (please scroll down):

```
module OrderLifecycle
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include ActiveSupport::Callbacks

  included do
    state_machine :initial => :pending do
      # States
      event :pre_authorize_stripe_payment do
        transition :pending => :stripe_payment_pre_authorized
      end

      event :write_encoded_preview_image_to_files do
        transition :stripe_payment_pre_authorized => :encoded_preview_image_written_to_files    # this line here!!! and...
      end

      event :render_final_image do
        transition :encoded_preview_image_written_to_files => :final_image_rendered
      end

      event :upload_composition_to_parse do
        transition :final_image_rendered => :composition_uploaded_to_parse
      end

      event :upload_print_file_to_printer do
        transition :composition_uploaded_to_parse => :print_file_uploaded_to_printer
      end

      event :call_to_process_message do
        transition :print_file_uploaded_to_printer => :process_message_called
      end

      event :capture_stripe_payment do
        transition :process_message_called => :stripe_payment_captured
      end

      event :mark_as_complete do
        transition :stripe_payment_captured => :complete
      end

      # Callbacks
      before_transition :on => :pre_authorize_stripe_payment do |order|
        PreAuthorizeStripePaymentJob.perform_later order
      end

      before_transition :on => :write_encoded_preview_image_to_files do |order|
        WriteEncodedPreviewImageToFilesJob.perform_later order # this line here!!!
      end

      before_transition :on => :render_final_image do |order|
        RenderFinalImageJob.perform_later order
      end

      before_transition :on => :upload_composition_to_parse do |order|
        UploadCompositionToParseJob.perform_later order
      end

      before_transition :on => :upload_print_file_to_printer do |order|
        UploadPrintFileToPrinterJob.perform_later order
      end

      before_transition :on => :call_to_process_message do |order|
        CallToProcessMessageJob.perform_later order
      end

      before_transition :on => :capture_stripe_payment do |order|
        CaptureStripePaymentJob.perform_later order
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My `config/sidekiq.yml` is

```
---
:verbose: true
:queues:
  - imagery_queue
  - parse_queue
  - stripe_queue
  - printer_api_queue
```

When I start Sidekiq initially the output to the terminal is:

```
2015-12-14T03:00:25.339Z 7664 TID-akza0 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 3.5.0 with redis options {:url=>"redis://localhost:6379"}


         m,
         `$b
    .ss,  $$b         .,d$
    `$$P,d$P'    .,md$$P'  ____  _     _      _    _
     ,$$$$$$bmmd$$$^'     / ___|(_) __| | ___| | _(_) __ _
   ,d$$$$$$$$$$$P         \___ \| |/ _` |/ _ \ |/ / |/ _` |
   $s^' `"^$$$'            ___) | | (_| |  __/   <| | (_| |
   $:     ,$$P            |____/|_|\__,_|\___|_|\_\_|\__, |
   `b     :$$                                           |_|
          $$:
          $$
        .d$$

2015-12-14T03:00:28.076Z 7664 TID-akza0 INFO: Running in ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
2015-12-14T03:00:28.077Z 7664 TID-akza0 INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2015-12-14T03:00:28.077Z 7664 TID-akza0 INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
2015-12-14T03:00:28.091Z 7664 TID-akza0 DEBUG: Middleware: Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::Logging, Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::RetryJobs, Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::ActiveRecord
2015-12-14T03:00:28.091Z 7664 TID-akza0 INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2015-12-14T03:00:28.104Z 7664 TID-wjesw DEBUG: {:queues=>["imagery_queue", "parse_queue", "stripe_queue", "printer_api_queue"], :labels=>[], :concurrency=>25, :require=>".", :environment=>nil, :timeout=>8, :poll_interval_average=>nil, :average_scheduled_poll_interval=>15, :error_handlers=>[#<Sidekiq::ExceptionHandler::Logger:0x00000002a28dc8>], :lifecycle_events=>{:startup=>[], :quiet=>[], :shutdown=>[]}, :dead_max_jobs=>10000, :dead_timeout_in_seconds=>15552000, :verbose=>true, :config_file=>"config/sidekiq.yml", :strict=>true, :tag=>"xxxxxxxxx"}
```

Comment: Are you sure your first job isn't failing anywhere?
You can try using 'pry' gem to debug.
Also inspect code to make sure your second job is indeed being called.

Comment: Hi @ShifaKhan. Yes, both these things :) See answer below!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in calling the `write_encoded_preview_image_to_files` method prematurely. Substituting `write_encoded_preview_image_to_files!` and inserting a `binding.pry` revealed:

```
     9: def run_phase_of_order_lifecycle(order)
    10:   response = create_stripe_charge(order)
    11:   if response['failure_code'] == nil
    12:     order.stripe_charge_id = response['id']
    13:     order.save!
    14:     binding.pry
    15:     order.write_encoded_preview_image_to_files!
    16:   end
 => 17:   response
    18: end

[1] pry(#<PreAuthorizeStripePaymentJob>)> order.state
=> "pending"
[2] pry(#<PreAuthorizeStripePaymentJob>)> order.write_encoded_preview_image_to_files!
StateMachines::InvalidTransition: Cannot transition state via :write_encoded_preview_image_to_files from :pending (Reason(s): State cannot transition via "write encoded preview image to files")
from /home/*****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/event.rb:224:in `block in add_actions'
[3] pry(#<PreAuthorizeStripePaymentJob>)> order.write_encoded_preview_image_to_files
```

Then checking the order's state in the rails console after the job had been processed:

```
2.2.2 :044 > Order.last.state
  Order Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders"  ORDER BY "orders"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => "stripe_payment_pre_authorized" 
2.2.2 :045 >
```

Therefore this problem may be solved by adding the following callback to the `OrderLifecycle` module:

```
after_transition :on => :pre_authorize_stripe_payment do |order|
  order.write_encoded_preview_image_to_files
end
```